# Prague and Pressburg and Rebbi Meir Shapira

Tags: sources-mekorot, politics-government

I have seen quoted that in the newspaper of Agudas Yisroel, Rebbi Meir Shapira printed an article named Prague and Pressburg and their differing approaches.

Does anyone have a copy or can link me a copy of the article?

Comment: see http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/214453/brisk-rosh-yeshiva-shlita-choose-between-prague-or-pressburg.html

Comment: still need a source please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sefer HaYovel](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43875&st=&pgnum=242&hilite=) which was published in honor of HaRav Meir Shapiro Zatzal while he was still alive has the entire article.

Comment: thanx a million - excuse the question but how did you find it

Comment: Siyata Dishmaya

Comment: may you have much further syata dishmaya - cheilcho leoraiysa